# Help in this inequality in Conway's complex analysis book

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 118 he write the following inequality:

[image]

Why is this inequality true?

Answer (score 1):

Triangle inequality $ | \int f | \leq \int |f| $, $|x+y| \leq |x| + |y|$ and the fact that $|e^{i \theta} | = 1 $

Comment: because it is $\log(p) + i \theta$, not $\log(p + i \theta)$ ? but I don't where comes the $p$ in the second $\frac{p}{|1-p^2[}$

Comment: maybe is there a typo in the numerator $|1-\rho^2|$? I can get the the inequality but with $|1+\rho^2|$ instead of $|1-\rho^2|$ in the numerator.

Comment: @user42912 : when $\theta = \pi$, $e^{i \theta} = -1$

Comment: @user1952009 Ok, but how can this fact solve my problem?

Comment: @user42912 really ? $|1+e^{i \theta} p^2| \ge 1-p^2$ hence $|\frac{1}{1+e^{i \theta} p^2}| \le \frac{1}{1-p^2}$ (whenever $|p| < 1$)

Comment: and the $p$ in $\frac{p}{1-p^2}$ is hidden at the beginning

Comment: @user1952009 I think I got it, thank you. Where do you use $|\rho|\lt 1$? I think we don't need this fact.

Comment: @user42912 : if $p=1$ there is clearly no such bound